# how to pull data from DB/datagridview/datatable

Tags: .net, vb.net, datagridview, datatable

I have this table.. and I want to pull a specific data..

[image]

Let's say.. I have Home Depot as a button. how can I pull the `CameraID` value of 2 and put it on a variable..
something like this..

```
'dim foo as string = cameraID where MarkerName is Home Depot
```

Comment: notice that ID and CameraID are the same value?  If you can't think of a situation where they could be different (which would mean a Camera could have DIFFERENT Lat/Long values) then it means the ID column is not needed and you could just use CameraID as your PK to simplify.

Comment: nope. ID is autonumbered (which I do not use too), whilst the CameraID, is user's input.. I just used 12345 cameraID for debugging the program, but generally, user can put, say, cameraID = 11 is on Home Depot.

Comment: then why do they have to give it any number at all?  If the ask to load the Mall camera, that should be all you need.  IDs and the like are typically up to the App to manage whilst the user refernces them however they want.

Comment: well you see. Autonumber as PK, so I won't have any problem when they were adding datas.. and so, if they add data, pick location on map, add a name, and add the camera that is in the place. and I reference on the `MarkerName` because that is only the connection that I have to the marker. Its really complicated and its not easy to explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given you use a `DataTable`, e.g.:

```
' example DataTable '
Dim dt = new DataTable()
dt.Columns.Add("cameraID", gettype(integer))
dt.Columns.Add("MarkerName", gettype(string))
dt.Rows.Add(new object() {2, "Home Depot"})
dt.Rows.Add(new object() {1, "CSI"})
```

you could use a LINQ-query:

```
' foo is now 2 '
Dim foo = dt.AsEnumerable() _
            .Where(function(row) row("MarkerName") = "Home Depot") _
            .Select(function(row) row("cameraID")) _
            .Single()
```

or the [`Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/det4aw50%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to filter the `DataTable`:

```
' foo2 is now 2 '
Dim foo2 = dt.Select("MarkerName = 'Home Depot'")(0)("cameraID")
```

Comment: thanks, you answered my question again, little do I know, all the workarounds do not work. this confirms it. :/