# Display Record According to DateTimePicker

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, ms-access-2007, datetimepicker

I have a database created using MS Access 2007. It contain a table `tbl_Order` with columns

```
Customer_Name, Dress_Type, Quantity, Date_Of_Pickup
```

I can display the record into datagridview using this code :-

```
 Private Sub dgvCurrentOrder()
        Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
        con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\TMS Final\TMS Final\db\db_TMS.accdb"

        If Not con.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            con.Open()
        End If

        Dim ds As New DataSet
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        ds.Tables.Add(dt)
        Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter

        da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT Customer_Name, Dress_Type, Quantity, Date_Of_Pickup " & _
                                        "FROM tbl_order " & _
                                        "ORDER BY Date_Of_Pickup ", con)

        dt.Clear()
        da.Fill(dt)

        dgvReminder.DataSource = dt.DefaultView

        dgvReminder.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect
    End Sub
```

it display all the orders from the database.. but what I want is to only display the order from current month..

The `Date_Of_Pickup` is in this format = `"28-Dec-2013"`

I've added a `datetimepicker, and modified the query to this :-

```
da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT Customer_Name, Dress_Type, Quantity, Date_Of_Pickup " & _
                                        "FROM tbl_order " & _
                                        "WHERE Date_Of_Pickup = " & dtpCurrent.Value.Month & " " & _
                                        "ORDER BY Date_Of_Pickup ", con)
```

I get an error

> Datatype mismatch in criteria expression

What should I do?

Comment: `dim dateTime = dataTabe.Select("Date_Time = 28-Dec-2013")(0)("ALL")`  
the "ALL" string should be a column.  
this is something like this : dim foo as string = get *ALL* where date&time is 28-Dec-2013 .. try some workaround. this is the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20514917/how-to-pull-data-from-db-datagridview-datatable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code selects rows where the column `Date_Of_Pickup` is greater than the last day of previous month.

```
Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = con.CreateCommand()

cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Customer_Name, Dress_Type, Quantity, Date_Of_Pickup " & _
                                "FROM tbl_order " & _
                                "WHERE Date_Of_Pickup > @DATE " & _
                                "ORDER BY Date_Of_Pickup "

Dim d As Date = dtpCurrent.Value

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DATE", New Date(d.Year, d.Month, 1, 23, 59, 59, 997).AddDays(-1.0#))


da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
```

If you would extract rows from the last 30 days you do:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DATE", Date.Now.AddDays(-30.0#))
```

Comment: the code works.. but i dont get it this part..
" 1, 23, 59, 59, 997 "
would you explain it to me?

Comment: When comparing dates, the time is also included in the comparison. So this creates a datetime like this: `d.Year, d.Month, FirstDayInMonth, LastHourOfDay, LastMinuteOfHour, LastSecondOfMinute, LastMillisecondOfSecond`.

Comment: And by subtract 1 day we get: `2013.11.30 23:59:59.997`. So the selection will begin with dates greater than this.